# WooCommerce add to cart ajax load

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a bundle product on my website. So when someone buys it, he will see in the cart total products 4.Also, I am showing the total product on the top mini cart. Now I want to update this top mini cart quantity by ajax when someone clicks on add to cart button.

Here is my code below:

```
$total_products=0;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
$total_products=$total_products+$cart_item['quantity'];

}
?>

<div class="shopping-cart-header <?php echo $height; ?>">

    <a class="mk-shoping-cart-link-2" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url();?>">
        <?php Mk_SVG_Icons::get_svg_icon_by_class_name(true, 'mk-moon-cart-2'); ?>
        <span class="mk-header-cart-count"><?php echo $total_products;?></span>
    </a>

    <div class="mk-shopping-cart-box">
        <?php the_widget('WC_Widget_Cart');?>
        <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce has its own ajax events which you can find in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js file.
Inside it you can find such trigger

```
// Trigger event so themes can refresh other areas.
$( document.body ).trigger( 'added_to_cart', [ response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton ] );
```

You need override these event inside your theme js file.

```
(function( $, document, window ) {

    // Add to cart event
    // NOTE: called on document ready event
    $( function() {
        $( document ).off( 'added_to_cart' ).on( 'added_to_cart', function( event, fragments, cart_hash, $button ) {
            $button = typeof $button === 'undefined' ? false : $button;

            // update counter
            var $counter = $( '.mk-header-cart-count' );
            var currentQuantity = parseInt( $counter.data( 'eg-product-count' ), 10 );
            var addedQuantity = parseInt( $button.data( 'quantity' ), 10 );
            var newQuantity = currentQuantity + addedQuantity;
            $counter.text( newQuantity );

            // Replace fragments.
            if ( fragments ) {
                $.each( fragments, function( key, value ) {
                    $( key ).replaceWith( value );
                });

                $( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragments_loaded' );
            }

            $( document.body ).trigger( 'cart_page_refreshed' );
        } );

    } );
})(jQuery, document, window);
```

I don't now how you integrate bundle realization so maybe you need implement it in addedQuantity variable.